# Why am I getting an error when I click chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a simple chrome extension. I was able to load the extension but when I clicked the extension icon next to the address bar I get an error : `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.` Why?

My **manifest.json** file :

```
{
    "name" : "Test",
    "version" : "0.1",
    "permissions" : ["<all_urls>", "tabs", "activeTab"],
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
            "js" : ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action" : {
        "default_popup" : "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version" : 2
}
```

**popup.html :**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.query({active : true, currentWindow : true}, (tabs)=>{
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action : "button_click"}, response =>{
        console.log(response);
    })
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse)=>{
    if(request.action === "button_click"){
        console.log("You clicked the button");
        sendResponse("success");
    }
})
```

**popup.js** is working fine because it is logging the response but **content.js** returns `undefined` response. **background.js** is still empty so I excluded it.
This is my first time diving into chrome APIs so I'm really confused as to why it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content scripts run only when a page loads for the first time in a tab so when you install or reload your extension on chrome://extensions page you also need to reload the tabs or [reinject the script explicitly](/q/10994324/). Also, by default content scripts run after DOMContentLoaded so it may be still pending injection if the page is still loading (you can tell it to run at [document_start](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time)).

Note that in your use case it's possible you don't need an automatically injected content script so you can remove `content_scripts` section, remove `<all_urls>` from `permissions`, and switch to [programmatic injection](/a/4532567) which can pass data even without messaging.

Comment: Indeed! I was reloading the extension but wasn't reloading the tabs which is why the error persists. I was looking at the code too much that I didn't think of reloading the tabs. 