# chrome.runtime.onMessage Listener is firing multiple times on a single sendMessage invoke

Tags: google-chrome-extension

On button click, I'm trying to send message, but my listener is invoked multiple times.

popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: "write", data: getData()}, function (response) { 
console.log(response,"!!!!");});
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(test);

function test(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "write") {
     console.log("write");
  }
 return true;
}
```

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The question is incomplete: you need to show how you declare/inject content.js. You either have `"all_frames": true` or calling executeScript multiple times.

Comment: This is how I have configured in manifest.json. 
 ``` "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "all_frames": false,
      "js": [
        "scripts/content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]```
and I have this statement  on button click. ```chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "scripts/content.js"});```

Comment: Remove chrome.tabs.executeScript - your script already runs automatically when you declare it in manifest.json.

Comment: Thanks much, Its working but earlier I was getting this error, so I placed that statement there. 'Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist'. Any Idea why this error occurs.

Comment: It means the content script wasn't running, which can happen if you reloaded the extension but forgot to reload the tab. Or the page was still loading and your content script doesn't have `"run_at": "document_start"`. See [Why am I getting an error when I click chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64153344)

Comment: You can keep your current code if you add the listener in content.js conditionally: if (!chrome.runtime.onMessage.hasListeners()) chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(test);

Comment: Sure, Thank you!!